Why is the Nats By Example pub-sub not working when using CLI but works using deno or other languages?
I'm new to Nats and have been going through the Nats by Example repo. I have the nats.exe for Windows in the root of my repo (I'm on Windows 11) and I'm trying to run the pub-sub example using ./nbe run messaging/pub-sub/cli but it fails right after the docker network is created shown below. I'm currently using Docker Desktop.
nbe run fails with CLI
I can run general nats CLI commands but I also get failure when trying to run ./nats server ls saying that the connection is refused.
nats server connection refused
The example runs fine when I run it using deno. Why doesn't the CLI work for this?
deno runs successfully
It works when running deno but fails using the CLI commands. I'm using Docker Desktop. I have the Nats CLI binary copied into the root of the repo.
